# How to build a Grails Plugin and deploy it to local Ivy repository?

Tags: grails, ivy

Is there a way to build a Grails Plugin and deploy the artifacts to the local Ivy repository?

With Maven, I would do this:

```
mvn install
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ivy [publish](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/publish.html) task

```
<ivy:publish resolver="local" pubrevision="1.0">
   <artifacts pattern="build/[artifact].[ext]" />
</ivy:publish>
```

### Note 1

Your ivy file must list the artifacts you plan to publish

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
  <info organisation="myorg" module="mymodule"/>
  <publications>
    <artifact name="mymodule" type="zip"/>
  </publications>
</ivy-module>
```

Maven derives this information from the module declaration in the POM file. One of the advantages of using ivy is that you can publish more than one artifact.

### Note 2

The ivy local repository is located in the following location by default:

```
${user.dir}/.ivy2/local
```

You can of course create your own custom repositories by declaring alternative resolvers in you settings file

Comment: Thanks for the info, Mark. Does this require a Maven POM defined for the grails project?  That's not ideal, as (in my experience) most Grails projects use Gant instead of Maven.

Comment: You only need a POM when you are publishing to Maven repository. Ivy can do that too, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111831/how-to-publish-3rdparty-artifacts-with-ivy-and-nexus/5115447#5115447

Comment: Ah, is the XML above for ant?