# Publish fails for large artifact

Tags: ant, ivy, artifactory

For a legacy project I'm currently introducing Ivy with Artifactory. I have some reusable scripts that work pretty well for jars and zips with sources. However, now **I need to publish several large artifacts** - zip-files, largest ~150MB. The publish fails with the following error-message:

> impossible to publish artifacts for com.siemens.nucleus.tmbo#TMBO-RELEASE;1.6-SNAPSHOT: java.io.IOException: Error writing to server
>
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error writing to server at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:578)

**A workaround is to change the order of artifacts**: small one first. **It seems it has something to do with authentication** - ivy seems to try with *anonymous* first, if that fails it tries with the configured user, but in the error case it only tries with anonymous, but twice (interpretation of Artifactory's access-log).
I'd rather go with a solution than a workaround - any ideas? **Can I force ivy to always use the credentials?**

Here is my ivy.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
    <info
        organisation="myorg"
        module="mymodule"
        revision="1.6-SNAPSHOT"
        status="integration" />

    <configurations>
        <include file="${ivy.confs.file}" />
    </configurations>

    <publications>
        <artifact name="large_artifact" ext="zip" type="deploy" />
        <artifact name="small_artifact" ext="zip" type="deploy" />
    </publications>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- None. -->
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

**EDIT:**

ivysettings.xml:

```
<ivy-settings>
    <settings defaultResolver="default" />
    <include url="ivysettings-shared.xml" />
    <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-local.xml" />

    <resolvers>
        <chain name="default" returnFirst="true" checkmodified="true">
            <resolver ref="local" />
            <resolver ref="shared" />
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivy-settings>
```

ivysettings-shared.xml:

```
<ivy-settings>
    <!--Authentication required for publishing (deployment). 'Artifactory Realm'
        is the realm used by Artifactory so don't change it. -->
    <credentials host="my-url.com" realm="Artifactory Realm"
        username="${ivy.repo.my-company.username}" passwd="${ivy.repo.my-company.password}" />
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="shared">
            <url name="my-releases" m2compatible="false">
                <artifact
                    pattern="https://my-url.com/artifactory/my-releases/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier])-[revision].[ext]" />
                <ivy
                    pattern="https://my-url.com/artifactory/my-releases/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/ivy-[revision].xml" />
            </url>
            <url name="my-snapshots" m2compatible="false">
                <artifact
                    pattern="https://my-url.com/artifactory/my-snapshots/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier])-[revision].[ext]" />
                <ivy
                    pattern="https://my-url.com/artifactory/my-snapshots/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/ivy-[revision].xml" />
            </url>
            <ibiblio name="my-external" m2compatible="true"
                root="https://my-url.com/artifactory/all" />
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivy-settings>
```

*ivy.repo.my-company.username* and *ivy.repo.my-company.password* are defined in a properties file *%IVY-HOME%\security.properties*

Comment: What's in your ivysettings file? That is where credentials are configured

Comment: See if this question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505062/publish-snapshot-artifacts-to-maven-using-ivy-whats-the-magic

Comment: @MarkO'Connor: please see my edit. Publish works for small files (like a charm for other modules with some jars), and I also tested authentication with good and bad users.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor: it seems my config is similar to the one you referenced (except for the maven stuff).