# How to deploy jar to nexus using Maven ant task

Tags: maven, ant

I am new to maven. How to deploy jar from build.xml to nexus repository. This document is referring to create a pom.xml. 
http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/install-deploy.html
What do I need to put in pom.xml. I have compile target in my build.xml and added below section to deploy the jar to nexus

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111831/how-to-publish-3rdparty-artifacts-with-ivy-and-nexus/5115447#5115447

Comment: I am trying to use maven ant task instead of ivy

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/install-deploy.html

Comment: What do I need to specify in the pom.xml ?